# python-fill-docstring-style to honor reST style

Tags: python

Given this input,

```
    """
    This is an example.

    * x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    * y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    - x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    - y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    1. x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    2. y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    : x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    : y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    :param hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    :param hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    @param hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an example.
    @param hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.
    """
```

fill-paragraph generates this.

```
    """ This is an example.

    * x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
    * this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is
    * an example.  y hi this is an example. hi this is an
    * example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi
    * this is an example.

    - x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
    - this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is
    - an example.  y hi this is an example. hi this is an
    - example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi
    - this is an example.

    1. x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
    this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example.  2. y hi this is an example. hi this is an
    example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this
    is an example.

    : x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
    this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example.  : y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi
    this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an
    example.

    :param hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example. hello this is an example.  :param hi this is an
    example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this
    is an example. hi this is an example.

    @param hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example. hello this is an example.  @param hi this is an
    example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this
    is an example. hi this is an example.  """
```

Two problems for me:

1. it didn't keep the line separated between each bullet.
2. `* and -` are treated specially and prepended for all lines. (I think it is related to `(set (make-local-variable 'paragraph-start) "\\s-*$")` in python.el

That is, I want to honor the heading of each bullet and keep lines between then. Those bullets are from rest style.

```
    """
    This is an example.

    1. x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
    this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
    example.
    2. y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is
    an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    * x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
      this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is
      an example.
    * y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is
      an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    - x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
      this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is
      an example.
    - y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is
      an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    : x hello this is an example. hello this is an example. hello
        this is an example. hello this is an example. hello this is
        an example.
    : y hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is
        an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an example.

    :param hello this is an example. hello this is an
           example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
           example. hello this is an example.
    :param hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this
           is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an
           example.

    @param hello this is an example. hello this is an
           example. hello this is an example. hello this is an
           example. hello this is an example.
    @param hi this is an example. hi this is an example. hi this
           is an example. hi this is an example. hi this is an
           example.
    """
```

I am using Using GNU Emacs 24.5.1. and `(setq python-fill-docstring-style 'django)`.

Comment: If you have a space between two bullet points, they will be correctly reformated